# Spinner text size not changing (programmatically)

Tags: android, android-spinner, text-size

I have a spinner, in the program I'm setting it's size like this:

```
final Spinner daySelection = layout.findViewById(R.id.day_selection);

            String []daySelectionValues = {"Today", "Tomorrow"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> daySelectionAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, daySelectionValues) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    adjustSize(view);
                    return view;
                }

                private void adjustSize(TextView view) {
                    CharSequence mystr = view.getText();
                    view.setText("Tomorrow");
                    float multisize = SharedFunctions.correctHeightAndWidth(view, 0.09*(float)(height - toolbarHeight)/(float)height, 1, windowManager);
                    view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, multisize);
                    view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    view.setText(mystr);
                }

                // Affects opened state of the spinner
                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    adjustSize(view);
                    return view;
                }
            };
            daySelection.setAdapter(daySelectionAdapter);
```

The xml file:

```
<Spinner
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/day_selection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3" />
```

The guidelines are 10% apart from each other. 
The problem can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

The dropdown text though is shown OK (when spinner is tapped):
[image]

The letter y is cut at the bottom. I tried to decrease the size of textview by setting it 4 times less:

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, multisize / 4);
```

But I end up with the following situation:

[image]

So it seems like it changes the dropdown list's text size by 4, but the textview of the spinner itself is not changed. I wonder if I'm doing it incorrectly?

Comment: have you tried changing the height of the spinner to wrap_content?

Comment: Just tried doing so, same thing. no change

Comment: Can you remove the padding too and let me know?

Comment: same, sorry no changes